# android toolbar is hidden when MaterialtabHost and Viewpager is used

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, material-design, android-toolbar

main_activity.xml

```
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MyActivity">

<!-- The main content view -->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#009688"
            />


        <it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabHost
            android:id="@+id/tabHost"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
         />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tabHost" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
<!-- The navigation drawer -->

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#F8F8F8"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false" />
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

I've created an material interface with navigation drawer and toolbar. Next I wanted to add two tabs to the screen,so I used tabHost lib. Now the toolbar is hidden and the tabs are displaying in place of the toolbar.
lib used :https://github.com/neokree/MaterialTabs/
In my design view it shows as exactly what I wanted link:http://postimg.org/image/ywxfbnksz/ But when I test on real device(Kitkat) toolbar is hidden

What's wrong with my implementation?

Comment: have you tried to use a real Fragment instead put the relativelayout to your FrameLayout?

Comment: how did you fix it? I have the same problem. Thx

Comment: I had similar issues have you tried making the height of each resource very small so that it all fits on the screen? Its not a case of hidden its a case of it being pushed out of the screen.

Comment: Use [SlidingTabsBasic](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/index.html) replace tabHost lib for your tabs. I used in my app working just fine

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28714046/4070044 This is my working code...