# android toolbar is hidden when Tabs are implemented

Tags: android-tabs, material-design, android-toolbar

I've created an app interface material design toolbar,drawer,fab everything works. Then I wanted to add 2 tabs ,so I used https://github.com/neokree/MaterialTabs library.Now the fragments and swipe action works .But the toolbar is now disappeared and tabHost is in place of it. In Android studio design view(not avd) it shows but when it came to real device(kitkat) it is not. I don't know what's wrong I've implemented the same way as in the test in lib module.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MyActivity">

<!-- The main content view -->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar" />


        <it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabHost
            android:id="@+id/tabHost"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            app:primaryColor="#009688"
            app:accentColor="#2B4AE0"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tabHost" />


        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
            android:id="@+id/multiple_actions"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/primary"
            fab:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/primary_pressed"
            fab:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="@color/white"
            fab:fab_labelStyle="@style/menu_labels_style"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp">

            <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/action_a"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white"
                fab:fab_title="Event"
                fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_attendance"
                fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/white_pressed" />

            <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/action_b"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white"
                fab:fab_title="Message"
                fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_message"
                fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/white_pressed" />

            <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/action_c"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white"
                fab:fab_title="Attendance"
                fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_events"
                fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/white_pressed" />

        </com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>


    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
<!-- The navigation drawer -->

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#F8F8F8"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Mine is working now. But I dont know how I fixed this. If you want, I can post the new xml.

Comment: ok, post the xml, thank you. are you using a new version of the it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabHost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the complete code I used, here I implemented tabs,toolbar and fab lib.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"


    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">


    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <!-- The main content view -->

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <RelativeLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">


                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
                    android:background="#2B4AE0"
                    app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/headerText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Theme"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/notification"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="end"
                        android:background="@drawable/butto_pressed"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        >

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="20dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"


                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:src="@drawable/bell_icon" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/frame"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

                    <it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabHost
                        android:id="@+id/tabHost"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        app:accentColor="@color/blue"


                        app:primaryColor="@color/white"
                        app:textColor="@color/blue" />

                    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                        android:id="@+id/pager"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/tabHost" />


                    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
                        android:id="@+id/multiple_actions"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                        fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/primary"
                        fab:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/primary_pressed"
                        fab:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="@color/white"
                        fab:fab_labelStyle="@style/menu_labels_style">

                        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                            android:id="@+id/action_a"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white"
                            fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/white_pressed"
                            fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_attendance"
                            fab:fab_title="Announcement" />

                        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                            android:id="@+id/action_b"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white"
                            fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/white_pressed"
                            fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_message"
                            fab:fab_title="Message" />

                        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                            android:id="@+id/action_c"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white"
                            fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/white_pressed"
                            fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_events"
                            fab:fab_title="Attendance" />

                    </com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>

                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
        <!-- The navigation drawer -->

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#F8F8F8"

            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```